# Javascript: Regex of a HTML h4 tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i have a variable "html" with an HTML code.

I need to extract:

```
<h4 class="search-results-count">ANY TEXT THAT GOES HERE</h4>
```

but i can't figure how to do that with regex or another tecnique

Comment: [Beware of parsing HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1654265)

Comment: Use jQuery. `$('.search-results-count').html()` or something like that. Do you have access to jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the innerHTML like

```
document.querySelector('.search-results-count').innerHTML
```

Comment: This is the preferred vanilla JS way to do it

Answer (score 0):

[You should not parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You can use the following regex: (not recommended)

```
<h4[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/h4>
```

And extract group 1.. `$1`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/11)